# How to reduce an image size using Glide before applying in PageViewer?

Tags: android, android-glide

I have created a PageViewer (sort of an onboarding screen) and am trying to insert 3 images in 3 different positions each. However, I am getting this error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(222964624bytes) bitmap.` so I need to reduce the size of the PNGs I am using despite the largest of them being only 344kB.

In my PageView Adapter class, I am using this to set the image:

```
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_screen, null);

        ImageView imgSlide = layout.findViewById(R.id.intro_image);
        imgSlide.setImageResource(mListScreen.get(position).getScreenImg());

        container.addView(layout);

        return layout;
```

If I wanted to use Glide to reduce the image size. Or actually any other solution is also welcome, how would I change that bit of code to accommodate this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void LoadImage(Context mContext, String Imageurl, ImageView view) {
     RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
         .signature(new ObjectKey(Imageurl))
         .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);

     Glide.with(mContext)
         .load(Imageurl)
         .apply(options)
         .thumbnail(0f)
         .into(view);
}
```

Usage

```
ImageView imgSlide = layout.findViewById(R.id.intro_image);
LoadImage(this,"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg",imgSlide);
```

For Drawable Load Change

```
.load(Imageurl)
```

By

```
.load(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mListScreen.get(position).getScreenImg()))
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but I did not understand the above function (I am relatively new to coding). So I call this function but how I would tackle the Imageurl parameter. I have the png in my drawable. And actually, where would I call the function?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Whats the purpose of this line: LoadImage(this,"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg",imgSlide);?